# How to feed SonarQube `sonar.python.xunit.reportPath` when only using Python `unittest` and `coverage.py`

Tags: python, unit-testing, sonarqube, coverage.py

I have create the unit tests for my python app using `unittest` and I use `coverage run` and `coverage report` (or `coverage xml`) to create the reports.
But I have to fed the reports into SonarQube. The problem is that I have also to fill the parameter `sonar.python.xunit.reportPath` (which seems to be the test execution report). Is there a way to fill this parameter using `coverage.py` and `unittest`?